# Stuck on GNOME; Can't change desktop environment

Tags: gnome, login-screen

I recently installed the GNOME desktop environment. I ran it and it worked well until I tried to change it back to the default Ubuntu one. I see the GNOME logo in the upper right hand corner, but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea on what could be causing this and how to fix it?

It is on the top right-hand corner of the log-in screen and only on the admin account. Other accounts are good.

[image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: I have added a picture... on question.  Yes it is on log-in screen @DavidFoerster

Comment: It is top-right corner. It is on log in screen sorry for that... it is shown before log-in... @DavidFoerster

Comment: Next to your user name there is a little gear you can alter to change the session, not when you log out, but after you reboot, try that one on.

Comment: I am using Gnome log-in screen @DavidFoerster

Comment: How about I post this as an answer and you mark it as a solution for the question to be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to your user name there is a little gear you can alter to change the session, not when you log out, but after you reboot, try that one on.